# maven build on jenkins not allowing to create/genarte any files in project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, cucumber

I have created a java project which has implemented cucumber and Junit.
When I am running the project from my IDE the reports and snapshots are generating finely but after pushing the code when my build is run by Jenkins, none of the reports and snapshot is generating in my workspace. My build also showing success without any issue, just the files are not created.

Configuration :-

- Window 10
- Jenkins.war -> Jenkins ver. 2.74

I am using the below command from terminal which is working fine

```
mvn clean install
```

In Jenkins maven plug-in, I have set goal as

```
clean install
```

I have also giving Full control permission to Jenkins war from properties->security.

It looks like a permission issue to me but what exactly it is?

I have also change the workspace from c driver to d still facing the same issue

Comment: What is the Maven command that your IDE executes (you can probably see it at the top of the logs). Compare that to the Maven command that Jenkins is executing in your build task. You can provide a lot of options to Maven to perform certain tasks i.e. `mvn test`, `mvn clean install`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for you reply. Yes I am using the exact same command "mvn clean install" from terminal and in jenkins I have set goal as "clean install".. is it fine?

Comment: Can you add debug option as `-X` and see what happens?

Comment: -x in jenkins? ...

Comment: When you say there are no files in your workspace - are you expecting Jenkins to create files in your personal workspace? Jenkins should build the artifact in its own workspace, not yours. By the way `-X` is the debug option, mvn will produce much more verbose output, try adding that to Jenkins and read the logs it produces when you build.

Comment: Thanks @Matt - Yes Jenkins is not creating the artifacts in Jenkins workspace while files are generated from my development env. -x in Maven or Jenkins? ... It appears to me as a Jenkins issue rather than maven as I am creating snapshots from java code which is nothing to do maven.

Comment: Jenkins builds your project with maven. When you give it the 'clean install' parameters it runs maven with those.

Comment: Yes correct, They are goals which execute accordingly.

Comment: Guys I am really sorry, Thats was a silly mistake. I have given the path of POM file of my dev env. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In configure -> build -> Root POM, the path of POM file should be of your Jenkins workspace projects not of your local/development env